# C# explicit casting of derived types

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, casting

If I create class A, and class B inherits from class A, why does C# require me to explicitly cast between them?

For example:

```
public class Mammal
{
}

public class Dog : Mammal
{
}
```

...

```
Mammal foo = new Dog(); // Invalid, wants an explicit cast
Mammal bar = (Mammal)new Dog(); // This one works
```

I'm just curious what the reasoning is behind that restriction.

Comment: The explicit cast shouldn't be required, and when I test your code the first version works just fine.  Could you post a more complete sample?

Comment: I wonder who would vote this question up when it implies up-casting doesn't work automatically.

Comment: Downvoted because this code actually works

Comment: Implicit casting from Dog to Mammal should work just fine.  Are you sure your problem isn't casting from Mammal to Dog?

Comment: This is a good place to mention http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean? Both statements you have written compile and work fine.

Did you mean to write this as your question...?

```
Dog foo = new Mammal(); // Invalid, wants an explicit cast
Dog bar = (Dog)new Mammal(); // This one works
```

If that was what you mean (which would match the comments) then the first one will not compile because a `Mammal` is not a `Dog` and the compiler knows it, so it won't let you assign it (a `Dog` is a `Mammal` because it is derived from it, but the converse does not hold true). In the second one you're overriding the compiler's better judgement, and telling it you know better that a `Mammal` really is a `Dog`, but as it isn't, this statement will fail at runtime with an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: And that would be a variance issue.  http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance%20and%20Contravariance/default.aspx

Comment: I was sure I had observed this before, but yes it appears my test code had the classes backwards

Comment: Correct; this is not a variance issue. For it to be a variance issue there has to be something like a generic type, array, method group conversion, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

They both work.